# How do I use a Bluetooth keyboard on bios

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B+.  I have a wireless mouse and a wireless internet stick. My keyboard is also Bluetooth but without an adapter.  I can use it only when i type in a code that is needed to connect the first time.  But I am already stuck in bios so how can I navigate with only the mouse? I bought this keyboard because it does not require a cable but I forgot that you cant use it at the beginning. So I am looking for a solution. I have a laptop. Can I use my laptop to configure everything so I can use my keyboard on the next boot?  You guys know how this work? I am a beginner.

Comment: **There is no BIOS to be stuck in** so you should *describe what is actually happening,* not what you think is happening.

Comment: @goldilocks I think he mistook the command line or `raspi-config` as the BIOS.

Comment: It does sound as though the OP needs to configure something on the Pi which will needs a keyboard - but his keyboard may not work without that configuration -  a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22) situation?

Comment: What software is on the SD card for the Pi is it "Raspbian"?  Did you have a kit with some stuff on the Card already or did you put stuff on there with your laptop.  The reason I ask is that if you have Raspbian on the card already you ought to be able to SSH into it - if your laptop is a Windows one you will want to install [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) on THAT first as a first step... IIRC you can get away with just a mouse if there is [NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) or NOOBS+Raspian on the card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are two types of wireless keyboard/ mouse kits available.

The one you seem to have is where the Operating System needs to start Bluetooth Utilities and connect to HID (Human Interface Device) This is a standard Bluetooth pairing system. Any device with Bluetooth will be able to connect to your kit **AFTER** pairing.

So you would need to use a wired USB keyboard to configure your Raspberry Pi first. After that "BIOS" screen, which is probaly just `raspi-config` you will need to log in, enable Bluetooth utilities, pair your Keyboard to the Bluetooth and enable a script to restart the Bluetooth Services on EVERY reboot.

---

The other type is just called Wireless (No Bluetooth in the name) and it also uses the 2.4ghz frequency band, but without pairing. This type of kit sometimes requires you to press a synchronise button on the mouse/keyboard but more commonly it is factory locked to a specific set already and doesn't require any buttons to be pressed.  ***This is the type of keyboard and mouse kit you require*** for it to work in "BIOS"/EFI on x86 type systems or SoC type systems with USB interface initialised in the firmware or early stages of bootloading.

The reason the second type works is because the pairing happens on the hardware and the `USB emulates a PS/2 keyboard`. This emulation of `PS/2` allows you to use your Wireless keyboard and mouse almost straight away after power on as its a really old keyboard/mouse standard that is supported by everything. It doesn't require extra drivers. (The "driver" is baked in to the USB specification, and is really just a standard, but that is why it works so well and early in boot)

> In Windows the drivers show up as HID just because that is how
>   Microsoft wants it to be. But on Unix type devices, or even BIOS, it
>   shows up as PS/2

---

*I for example have the Microsoft Wireless Keyboard and Mouse 3000 set. I can plug this into the Pi and have mouse and keyboard access straight after plugging in the USB. The USB is locked to a single set of keyboard and mouse, so you just put batteries in. I also successfully used this keyboard on Android with OTG, my TV and various other devices. Just because the USB emulates PS/2*