# How to enter Recovery Mode without USB keyboard?

Tags: pi-3, keyboard, recovery

At boot, I know you can enter to Recovery screen by holding shift. However, I don't have access to a usb keyboard for now. However, a bluetooth keyboard is configured with my Raspberry Pi 3, but it isn't connected right away at boot screen.

Anyway, how can I have access to recovery with only a bluetooth keyboard / no keyboard at all?

Thanks :)

Comment: You may find this answer to be helpful: [How do I use a Bluetooth keyboard on bios](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39745/46007)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forcetrigger`.  From the NOOBS readme:

> If you are unable to use either the GPIO or keyboard to trigger
>   entering Recovery Mode, you can:
>
> 1. Append `forcetrigger` to the argument list in the `recovery.cmdline` file which is found in the root NOOBS directory.
> 2. Reboot.
>
> Note that with this option enabled, the Recovery Mode will be displayed every time you boot from your NOOBS card (until you edit `recovery.cmdline` again).

You can edit your the `recovery.cmdline` with the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/mmcblkOp1 /mnt
sudo nano /mnt/recovery.cmdline
```

Source: https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/blob/master/README.md#how-to-force-recovery-mode-being-entered-on-boot-overrides-gpio-or-keyboard-input